# How to indent multiple lines starting from the middle in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

For example, to convert this

```
$example = array(
    'First' => 'This,
    'Second' => 'is',
    'Third' => 'an',
    'Fourth'=> 'example',
    'Fifth' => '.',
);
```

into this

```
$example = array(
    'First'     => 'This',
    'Second'    => 'is',
    'Third'     => 'an',
    'Fourth'    => 'example',
    'Fifth'     => '.',
);
```

without having to indent each `=> 'whatever',` each time.

Is this possible to do in [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)?

Comment: In this particular case `:s/=>/\t\0/g` (optionally followed by `:retab`) could be enough

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, and I think is preferable to the other solutions as it doesn't require a plugin

Answer (score 2):

There are two Vim plugins for that, [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) and [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). With Align, select the lines and execute

```
:'<,'>Align =>
```

Tabular is a more recent alternative to the venerable Align, but both offer similar functionality. Pick according to your preferences.

Comment: For the record, this has my vote, as it is immensely versatile. I don't usually miss any plugins for vim except when I don't have `surround.vim` or `align.vim :)

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Ingo's answer, here is how you do it with Tabular:

```
:'<,'>Tabularize /=>
```