# How to Re-Indent visually selected column in Vim

Tags: vim

I have some text like,

[image: Variables]
I would like to move variable2,var3 and var4 so that all four variables are aligned together. I am able to visually select the column, using <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>. But after that how can I reindent or delete the extra spaces in front of variable2, var3 and var4?

Please not that moving variable1 is not an option as there are multiple lines that are aligned with variable1. Also I can not use plugins.

Is there a easier way to do this without using any plugins, through basic vim commands?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're open to plugins, this is often done with tabular.vim http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174568/how-to-indent-multiple-lines-starting-from-the-middle-in-vi, also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268447/alignment-in-vim

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I cannot use plugins.

Comment: I use Align.vim (`\tsp`)

Comment: Is there a easier way to do this without using any plugins. through basic vim commands

Comment: I've posted one based on the `\%V` pattern modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your cursor on the second line, just below the 'v' in 'variable1'.
Select down a column and delete it. This is, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

Repeat it (<kbd>.</kbd>) as many times as you desire.

Undo (<kbd>u</kbd>) if you went too far deleting columns. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You could do that block selection and then

```
:'<,'>s/\v%V\s+//
```

What this does is 'zap' all contiguous starting whitespace found inside the visual selection.

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without a plugin, the easiest way to align that specific example is to visually select the 2x3 column below <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, as you've already noted, and then hit <kbd>x</kbd> to delete it. I can't think of a more-generic solution without using plugins.

You could also do something repeatable, like place the cursor before the unwanted space, hit <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to delete the two spaces, use <kbd>j</kbd> to move down, and then use <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat the two-character delete. Repeat on subsequent lines.

Finally, you can create a [macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros) to handle other patterned commands, but creating the right macro for variable alignment situations will require some practice and is a bit outside the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with VISUAL BLCOK:

assume your cursor at the beginning of 2nd line, (`c of char`), you could:

<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

you can do it with macro too, assume cursor was still at `char`, for single line, you could do:

```
w2X
```

then you can record as:

```
qqw2Xj0q
```